# How to get a value to change immediately after a button is pressed in tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

When the rock button is pressed I want your score to go up by one immediately after you press the button. However the score updates on the button press after instead of immediately updating after one button press. To see what I mean press the rock button twice and you will get a score of 1. How would I fix this problem?

```
from tkinter import *
import random


root = Tk()
results = Label(root)
your_score = 0

def rock_input():
    global results
    global your_score

    options = ['scissors']
    cpu = random.choice(options)

    win = Label(root, text='you win!!!')
    human_score = Label(root, text='Your score: ' + str(your_score))

    win.config(font=('Courier', 44))
    human_score.config(font=('Courier', 15))
    results.grid_forget()

    if cpu == 'scissors':
        your_score += 1
        human_score.grid(row=2, column=1)
        results = win
        results.grid(row=4, column=0)


rock_button = Button(root, text='rock', bg='#a85032', padx=20, pady=15, command=rock_input)
rock_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: idk if its really a choice but changing `your_score = 0` to `your_score = 0` will solve the issue  for now, tho im trying a better way

Comment: actually the prob is wenever the button is pressed the funtion starts so then the initial value of `your_score` is taken instead you need to put it `if` block mayb?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried playing around with your code and im not sure what you're trying to achieve, so pardon me if im wrong. I think there is two ways to achieve what i think you want.

**Way 1 (does not change your function code):**

Simply changing `your_score = 0` to `your_score = 1` will fix the issue for now.

**Way 2 (change inside your function, rearranging the code):**

```
def rock_input():
    global results
    global your_score

    options = ['scissors']
    cpu = random.choice(options)
    if cpu == 'scissors':
        your_score += 1
        win = Label(root, text='you win!!!')
        human_score = Label(root, text='Your score: ' + str(your_score))

        win.config(font=('Courier', 44))
        human_score.config(font=('Courier', 15))
        results.grid_forget()

        human_score.grid(row=2, column=1)
        results = win
        results.grid(row=4, column=0)
```

Let me know if any errors or doubts :D

Comment: it works but I still don't get why this works and the original doesn't. Could you explain that, please?

Comment: because python reads code line by line and executes each line nd proceeds, u set initial value of score to 0 and later ur label is using tht initial value (which is 0) but later on inside the `if` block u said to increment it by 1 which wont get affected unless the `if` block is executed so the initial value gets read first (which is 0) then label shows 0 and then it adds 1 and in d next press of button the value of score is nw 1 and that is shown by label. Its simple if u think abt it